# File association with ionic 2

Tags: cordova, ionic2, file-association

I need to add my App to the list of apps associated with a file type. for example, When trying to open a pdf from email it will show my app in the list of "open with" apps. 
I am writing in ionic 2. I couldn't find detailed explanation to do it with Cordova. can someone share his knowledge please?

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks/ is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't think that this is what I need, How does it help to open my app in case I click on a pdf which was attached to a mail I received? I may be missing something. can u explain?